# Wiggins doubt in the exercise 19.4 5.

Tags: dynamical-systems

I'm working in the text "Introduction to Applied Nonlinear Dynamical Systems and Chaos"and I have a doubt in the following  exercise

> Consider a third-order autonomous vector field near a fixed point having linear part
> $$\left(\begin{matrix}
> 0&-\omega&0\\
> \omega&0&0\\
> 0&0&0
> \end{matrix}\right)$$
> find the normal form. (Hint: Lump the two coordinates associated with the block$$\left(\begin{matrix}
> 0&-\omega\\
> \omega&0
> \end{matrix}\right)$$
> into the single complex coordinate.)

My doubt is what means: Lump the two coordinates associated with the...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: Complex numbers can be represented as real matrices that obey all of the same operations by the following (field) isomorphism: $$a+bi \leftrightarrow \begin{pmatrix}a & -b \\ b & a\end{pmatrix}$$